# Sacar un valor de un metodo

Tags: java, array, método

Buenas Compañeros tengo un problema. 
Tengo el siguiente metodo:

```
public void repartirPC1() {
        try {
            CartasPc1[0] = (int) (Math.random() * 13);
            CantidadCartas[CartasPc1[0]]--;
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Problemas al ejecutar revisar 1");
        }

        try {
            CartasPc1[1] = (int) (Math.random() * 13);
            CantidadCartas[CartasPc1[0]]--;
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Problemas al ejecutar revisar 2");
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("PC 1 tiene: ");

        //System.out.println("test: "+ valorCartas[2]);
        //Interpretar el valor de las cartas.
        int num1, num2; // variables para poder enmascarar el valor de las cartas y efectuar la suma
        num1 = CartasPc1[0];
        num2 = CartasPc1[1];
        //Asignacion de los valores de las cartas mediante un variable temporal
        tempSume += getCart(num1); // Brinda el numero de la carta
        tempSume += getCart(num2); // Brinda el numero de la carta
        Suma = tempSume;
        // System.out.println("Numeros del arreglo " + num1 + " , " + num2); // Para conocer la posicion del arreglo a la hora de imprimir
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Para su Juego tiene un total de: " + Suma);

    }
```

y requiero de sacar el valor de la suma para compararlo en otro metodo.

```
public void demostracion() {
        int suma1=0, suma2=0;
        PC p = new PC();
        p.repartirPC1();

        this.tempSume = suma1;

        System.out.println(" temporal 1  " + this.tempSume);
        System.out.println(" temporal  2 " + suma1);

        System.out.println(" temporal  3 " + getSuma());
```

Pero siempre me da cero el valor, ya lo declare como variable global y le puse `Get` y set para poder obtener los valores pero no logro como sacar el valor .
Agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Podrías incluir el código de la clase PC por favor?

Comment: Ok, tratare de subirlo

Comment: En el método demostracion(), creaste la variable suma1 y le diste valor 0... luego le diste el valor de suma1 (que es 0) a tu otra variable tempSume y es por eso que siempre obtienes 0 de resultado, porque nunca cambian de valor

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no puedo ver todo tu código, estoy casi seguro que es un problema de referencias, si necesitas acumular las sumas, declara "suma" como "static".
Si haces esto automáticamente la variable es de la clase y solo existe una instancia en memoria al momento de la ejecución(No importa si creas mas objetos de la misma clase).

```
public static int suma;
```

Comment: Lo intentare, los estuve declarando estaticos para poderlos llamar pero me genero problemas

Answer (score 0):

Podrias agregar un `return Suma` para devolver la suma al final de tu funcion repartirPC1() y en tu funcion demostracion() agregar algo como esto `sum=p.repartirPC1();`, o en caso de no que te sirva, haz lo siguiente:

```
public int suma;

public int getSuma()
    {
            return suma;
    }
public void setsuma(int suma)
    {
            this.suma= suma;
    }
```

asi en tu funcion repartirPC1 guardas al final de esta manera:

```
setSuma(Suma)
```

y en tu clase demostracion() lo llamas de esta manera:

```
p.getSuma();
```